# Does Facebook still support proxymail email addresses?

Tags: facebook

Facebook used to allow users to hide the email addresses sent to Facebook applications by providing on that looks like `xxxx@proxymail.facebook.com`. I can no longer find a way to do this. The control on the authorization dialog for this is gone. But I cannot find any mention of it being deprecated either.

Does Facebook still support proxymail email addresses?
Is it assumed now that the application will always get the user's real email address?

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Facebook no longer issues proxymail addresses.